# C++ syntax question - Why can't I use comma to separate variable definition of different types

Tags: c++, syntax

```
int main() {
  std::cout << 1, std::cout << 2;
  return 0;
}
```

The above snippet is syntactically correct, as commas can be used to separate statements. However,

```
int main() {
  int a, std::string b;
  return 0;
}
```

This returns with an error

> Expected initializer before 'b'

Why is this? Is there some circumstances I cannot use a comma to separate statements? For example in this case definition of variables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Commas *never* separate statements.  Your first example is a single statement, consisting of an expression containing the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator).  It happens to do the same thing as if you had written two statements `std::cout << 1; std::cout << 2;` but they're not syntactically equivalent.

Likewise, your second example is (trying to be) a single declaration statement, and it's not a syntactically valid one.  It is possible to use a comma (not as the comma operator)to separate two declarations of the same type `int a, b;` with some variations such as `int a, *b;`, but this is still one declaration statement.

Comment: Which part is the expression?

Comment: `std::cout << 1, std::cout << 2` is an expression.  Everything but the semicolon.

Comment: And perhaps one of the points of confusion is that `std::cout << 1` and `std::cout << 2` are expressions, too.  That's part of the reason that you can chain additional output operations onto each.  Expressions can be used as statements by terminating them with a semicolon, but not all statements are expressions.

Comment: how do I know that  `std::cout << 1, std::cout << 2` is an expression?

Comment: but `int a, string b` is not?

Comment: @LearningMathematics It's just how the language rules are specified.

Comment: @cigien so is it specified that `cout` can be chained with commas and the whole thing will still be an expression?

Comment: If it is the case, then where can I find the information?

Comment: @LearningMathematics: **Any** two expressions can be the operands of the comma operator.  See the link I gave above, or https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/07/31/how-to-get-along-with-the-comma-operator/ for a briefer introduction.  It's a general fact about C++: binary operators take two operands, each of which is an expression, and the combination of `expression operator expression` is itself an expression.  This sort of recursive definition is fundamental in understanding programming language syntax.

Comment: @LearningMathematics There are a number of resources that you can avail of. In general, I would recommend using [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) as your primary reference. You can also lookup the official rules in the standard text, but this is mostly unnecessary.

Comment: @LearningMathematics Compare `if (false) std::cout << 1; std::cout << 2;` with `if (false) std::cout << 1, std::cout << 2;` That will show how there is a big syntactical difference.

Comment: @LearningMathematics • You can create both `a` and `b` in one statement by doing `auto [a, b] = std::make_tuple<int, std::string>(0, "");`.